# Can't set CSS variables with Parcel and postcss-custom-properties

Tags: css, fullcalendar, postcss, css-variables, parceljs

I'm trying to style my [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) according to technique 2 as described in [this documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization). It says I should use *PostCSS* with *postcss-custom-properties* and *postcss-calc*.

My project uses [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) for bundling and not WebPack like FullCalendar do in their examples, but from my understanding, [using PostCSS in Parcel](https://parceljs.org/css.html) should just be plug-and-play by including a **postcss.config.js** file, so I figured it shouldn't be a huge issue. Here's what that file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
      "grid": true
    }),
    require('postcss-custom-properties')({
      preserve: false,
      importFrom: [
        'src/style/fullcalendar-vars.css' 
      ]
    }),
    require('postcss-postcss-calc')
  ]
};
```

So I have a file **src/style/fullcalendar-vars.css**. For the purpose of testing, it looks like this:

```
:root {
  --fc-button-bg-color: red;
}
```

But nothing changes. When I look in the dev tools, there are no CSS variables set. Did I miss something?

I don't know if I can give you more information, I can't share a Stackblitz or anything else afaik, because the proplem lies in the building process. But I can link to the github repository where I am right now so you can look in other files and see what can be wrong https://github.com/WestCoastJitterbugsOrg/Personalized-Calendar/tree/c7633401cb1bb50488e11d0d306cb11333961f2d

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was that I used scss for everything else. A much simpler solution was to change the file extension of `fullcalendar-vars.css` to `scss` and import it in `main.scss`. No hassle, everything works like a charm! Finally I can have my pretty bright red buttons ;)